# iOS UITableView deleted cell contents re appear when inserting new cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I've a table view where cells can be inserted and deleted. For insertion of cells, I use the following code:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: cellCount-2, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

For deleting cells, I use the following code:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Attaching the gif of the issue I face. On deleting a cell and inserting a new one, the contents of the cell gets populated in the new cell. Can someone help me sort this issue?

[image]

Comment: Table cells are reused.  In `cellForRowAt`, make sure you initialize the score and date fields after dequeuing a reusable cell.

Comment: have you deleted the row from your datasource?? chances are the original still has instance of the data so its being displayed again.

Comment: @vacawama I set the textfields to be blank in  cellForRowAt and it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: blanking rows doesn't do anything to remove fact that rows still exist in your datasource array for the tableview.

Comment: Your rows should be backed by a datasource.  In your case, it could be an array containing a struct with score and date fields.  You should add items to this array when you add rows to your table, and you should delete items from this array when you delete rows.  `cellForRowAt` should be referencing this datasource for setting up the cell.  This will allow everything to work correctly when you start getting more cells and they start scrolling off the screen.  Be sure to update your datasource when the user enters a score or date.

Comment: @vacawama I'm updating my datasource and still it happened. That's why I posted this question. And the information is coming from cell class upon endEditing of text field.

Comment: It wouldn't happen if you always set the score and date from the datasource.  When a new row is added, first add a new record to your datasource, then call `tableView.insertRows`.  When you delete a row, delete it from the datasource and then call `tableView.deleteRows`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the standard `UITableViewCell` remember to reset the content inside the UITableViewDelegate function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` since the `dequeueReusableCell` will recycle an already initialized cell (that has to be brought to its original state)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)!
    ...
    cell.title.text = ""
    cell.description.text = ""
}
```

A typical approach is however to subclass `UITableViewCell` and implement `prepareForReuse` method (which is called automatically before the cell being reused), where you will eventually reset all labels, images, subviews to the initial state

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
     super.prepareForReuse()
     self.labelScore.text = ""
     self.labelDate.text = ""
}
```